# Amazon SNS silent pushes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

In [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem and Amazon developer docs I tried to find any information about `SNS` silent pushes, but it seems very contradictorily. 
I am confusing that in SNS Client message is required, but is it possible to send exactly silent GCM and APNS notifications?

Does anybody have information about it? 
Any advice/resource will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Amazon AWS SNS docs about silent push notifications are not very helpful, but it works.
I am sende silent push notifications via AWS SNS service via Lambda Node.js to iOS devices via Apple APNS

**SEND AWS SNS SILENT PUSH NOTIFICATION TO APNS with Node.js**

```
var sns = new AWS.SNS();

var data = {myString:'silent push'}; // payload data object 
sns.publish({
    TargetArn: snsTopicArn,
    MessageStructure: 'json',
    Message: JSON.stringify({
        default: 'silent push!',
        APNS_SANDBOX: JSON.stringify({
            aps: {
                'alert': '',
                'content-available': 1
            },
            'data': JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    })
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can send messages to SNS [using JSON format](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/336#issuecomment-22999893), so you should be able to set `content-available` and [set the alert as you wish](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html).

For Android I think it would be the same (but as Android handles notification differently you should be able to handle any payload and don't show the notification)

Answer (score 0):

For android, if you don't send "message" inside GCM object it will be a silent push notification. This aligns with the GCM [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

```
 GCM: {
      data: {
          // message: 'hello'
      }
  }
```